# What is the command equivalent to git clone -b on old Git versions?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone

A friend is stuck with an old version of Git (I think he said 1.5?), where he says the `-b <branch>` option is not supported. I can't wrap my head around it, so I really hope someone could help:

What would be the equivalent of the following command, without using `-b`?

```
git clone -b $BRANCH $REPO
```

EDIT: I originally asked for `git checkout` - that's not what I meant. Sorry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in older git this required two steps:

```
git branch $BRANCH $FROM_COMMIT
git checkout $BRANCH
```

notice i used `$FROM_COMMIT`, `$REPO` in your question looks odd and misleading – you can only create branches from commits, not from other repositories.

---

editing my answer, since the question was altered. reading the manpage for git clone, we can see that

> -b
>
> Instead of pointing the newly created HEAD to the branch pointed to by the cloned repository’s HEAD, point to  branch instead. In a non-bare repository, this is the branch that will be checked out.

to achieve this effect with an older git version we would use:

```
git clone $REPO
git branch $BRANCH origin/$BRANCH
git checkout $BRANCH
```

this will set your local `HEAD` to the newly created `$BRANCH` which is pointing to `origin/$BRANCH`

(hopefully i'm not mistaken – i don't have a git install here to test …)

Answer (score 4):

He should be able to do:

```
git clone -n $REPO
cd <reponame>
git checkout -b $BRANCH origin/$BRANCH
```

I've checked that the options are valid for v1.2.0 so this should be good if he's on at least 1.5.

For reference, clone only gained the `-b`/`--branch` option in v1.6.5.

Answer (score 2):

That would be:

```
git clone -n $REPO
git checkout -b $BRANCH origin/$BRANCH
```

(see [Charles Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19563/charles-bailey)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741490/help-with-old-git/5741689#5741689) for the right answer)

If you don't fetch the default branch from the `HEAD` repo, <del>you need to fetch the branch you actually want to track, and then create your own local branch</del>.

---

I would have deleted this answer, but Charles Bailey's comments are interesting:

> There's no point in fetching immeditately after a clone but you might want to pass `-n` to `clone` **to avoid the unnecessary checkout of the remote's default branch**.
>   Also, you need the `-b` option to `checkout`.
>
> I've just checked, `-b` was added to `checkout` in commit `91dcdfd3` which predates `v1.0` of git.
>   If your friend is using a version older than this (which seems extremely unlikely) then you need to be more specific.

Comment: I am getting error messages on the checkout line: `git checkout $BRANCH origin/$BRANCH` //
`error: pathspec '$BRANCH' did not match any file(s) known to git.` //
`error: pathspec 'origin/$BRANCH' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: There's no point in fetching immeditately after a clone but you might want to pass `-n` to `clone` to avoid the unnecessary checkout of the remote's default branch. Also, you need the `-b` option to checkout.

Comment: Would this work instead? `git checkout origin/$BRANCH` and then `git branch $BRANCH`, and then somehow (how?) set up tracking? (not that great at Git yet)

Comment: @Charles: The whole point to this exercise is that apparently the option `-b` is not available. It's not my installation so I can't check :(

Comment: @Amadan: `-b` to checkout, not to clone. `-b` has been available to checkout since well before 1.5.

Comment: @Amadan: I've just checked, `-b` was added to checkout in commit 91dcdfd3 which predates v1.0 of git. If your friend is using a version older than this (which seems extremely unlikely) then you need to be more specific.